# Issues with scripting Management Service Delegation Add Rule... and Add User To Rule

Tags: powershell, iis, webdeploy, windows-server-2016

I am trying to script with Powershell adding a role and adding a user to the role on Management service delegation on Windows server 2016. Unfortunately I have not been able to find any documentation on how this is done.

I have Web deploy 3.6 installed and can see the Management service delegation module in IIS.

I know that doing this via the IIS UI is trivial but I need to get it scripted via powershell. If anyone could assist it would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I ended up peeking into the WebDeploy AddDelegationRules.ps1 script to figure this one out. This will create a new Management service delegation rule and add a user to the rule.

```powershell
$serverManager = (New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager)
$delegationRulesCollection = $serverManager.GetAdministrationConfiguration()
.GetSection("system.webServer/management/delegation").GetCollection()


$newRule = $delegationRulesCollection.CreateElement("rule")
$newRule.Attributes["providers"].Value = $provider
$newRule.Attributes["actions"].Value = "*"
$newRule.Attributes["path"].Value = $path
$newRule.Attributes["pathType"].Value = $pathType
$newRule.Attributes["enabled"].Value = "true"

$runAs = $newRule.GetChildElement("runAs")
$runAs.Attributes["identityType"].Value = "CurrentUser"

$permissions = $newRule.GetCollection("permissions")
$user = $permissions.CreateElement("user")
$user.Attributes["name"].Value = "*"
$user.Attributes["accessType"].Value = "Allow"
$user.Attributes["isRole"].Value = "False"
$permissions.Add($user) | out-null

$delegationRulesCollection.Add($newRule) | out-null
$serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

Comment: Before I could run your first line of code, I had to Load this Assenbly: [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll" )