# Issues with scripting Management Service Delegation Add Rule - saving passwords

Tags: powershell, iis, webdeploy, windows-server-2016

Realting to [57291237](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291237/issues-with-scripting-management-service-delegation-add-rule-and-add-user-to).

I've reused the script and it works almost fine. There is one bit that doesn't work for me - when calling the CreateDelegationRule function:

```
CreateDelegationRule($providers, $path, $pathType, $identityType, $userName, $password, $enabled)
```

with

```
CreateDelegationRule "appPoolNetFx, appPoolPipeline" "{userScope}" "PathPrefix" "SpecificUser" "WDeployConfigWriter" "PASSWORD" "true"
```

all the fields are correctly filling up despite the password. In order to make it work I need to set the password manually in the UI, which kills all the concept of scripting it.

Am I doing something wrong or it's just not possible to provide the password using the script?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are only 2 parameters in the CreateDelegationRule method, one is Http.Sys request queue and the other is Http.Sys Url Prefix, but there are 7 parameters in your method.

More information about how to use CreateDelegationRule method you can refer to this link:

[IServerDelegationFeature.CreateDelegationRule(String, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.httpsys.iserverdelegationfeature.createdelegationrule?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: I'm particularly talking about the script provided by MS itself, located in `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\Scripts\AddDelegationRules.ps1` and `CreateDelegationRule` function. You can see it takes7 args: $providers, $path, $pathType, $identityType, $userName, $password, $enabled. For some reason I am not able to provide the password argument the right way :/

Comment: Sorry I did not find the Scripts folder under Microsoft Web Deploy V3.